# Is it possible to solve $\int_{0}^{1} t^4 \sqrt{1+t^2}\,dt$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How should I solve the below integral?$$\int_{0}^{1} t^4 \sqrt{1+t^2}\,dt$$

Comment: Integration by parts and possibly trigonometric substitution.

Comment: Try to substitute $t = i\sin(u)$, where $i$ is the imaginary unit.

Comment: Define $u = \sqrt{1+t^2}$.

Comment: The most obvious trig approach is $u=\tan(\theta)$, which gives $\sqrt{1+t^2}=\sec(\theta)$ and $dt=\sec(\theta)^2 d \theta$. The resulting trig integral is doable but difficult.

Comment: @RicardoCervantes That gives I guess $\frac{1}{2} \int (u^2-1)^{3/2} u^2 du$; is that so much better than what you started with?

Comment: @Ricardo: Doesn't that just change the way the integrand looks? You'll still have a square root term from the $du$ part, I believe

Comment: @ it is true. iT is no bueno, I solved the exercise and I had a mistake

Comment: The change of variable $t=\sinh x$ yields $t^4=\sinh^4x$, $\sqrt{1+t^2}=\cosh x$ and $dt=\cosh x\,dx$ hence one is left with some tedious but easy integral to evaluate.

Comment: another approach sqrt(1+t^2)+t=u  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1+%7Bt%5E4sqrt(1%2Bt%5E2)%7Ddt

Answer (score 5):

By setting $t=\sinh u$ we get:
$$ I=\int_{0}^{\log(1+\sqrt{2})}\sinh^4(u)\cosh^2(u)\,du=\\\frac{1}{64}\int_{0}^{\log(1+\sqrt{2})}\left(4+e^{-6 u}-2 e^{-4 u}-e^{-2 u}-e^{2 u}-2 e^{4 u}+e^{6 u}\right)\,du $$
that is not a difficult integral to compute, just a tedious one. It boils down to:

> $$ I = \color{red}{\frac{7}{48}\sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{16}\log(1+\sqrt{2})}.$$

Comment: Quite a bit more elegant than the trig integral that results from the substitution $u = \tan(\theta)$. +1 of course.

Comment: Another approach could be to write the integral in the form $0.5t^3*2t\sqrt{1+t^2}$ and perform integration by parts. What happens is that behind the integral sign you now get a quadratic $t$ with a squareroot. If you perform a trig or hyperbolic sub on that integral, things work out quicker because the polynomial term upfront is only a quadratic The method of Jack becomes quite easy then...

Comment: It might be less tedious to derive the recursion $$I_n={\sqrt2\over n+1}-{2n-1\over2n+2}I_{n-1}$$ where $I_n=\int_0^1t^{2n}\sqrt{1+t^2}dt$, which lets you get to $$\int_0^1t^4\sqrt{1+t^2}dt={\sqrt2\over12}+{1\over8}\int_0^1\sqrt{1+t^2}dt$$ in two steps.

Comment: I disagree that the evaluation need be so tedious! Since $\sqrt2+1$ and $1/(\sqrt2+1)=\sqrt2-1$ are algebraic conjugates, one can just store the former constant in memory and punch out exponentials as powers of the constant, knowing that the answer will be $N\times\sqrt2/D$, where $D$ is a common denominator, so $\text{answer}\times D\div\sqrt2$ will be an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the integral
$$I =\int_0^1 t^4\sqrt{1+t^2}\,\text{d}t,$$

use the substitution $t = \tan(\theta)$, $\text{d}t = \sec^2(\theta)\,\text{d}\theta$; when $t = 0$, $\theta = 0$, when $t=1$, $\theta =\pi/4$. This yields the integral
$$I = \int_0^{\pi/4} \tan^4(\theta)\sqrt{1+\tan^2(\theta)}\sec^2(\theta)\,\text{d}\theta = \int_0^{\pi/4} \tan^4(\theta)\sec^3(\theta)\,\text{d}\theta$$
Now integrate by parts, using $\text{d}v = \tan^4(\theta)\sec^2(\theta)\,\text{d}\theta$, $u=\sec(\theta)$.
\begin{align}
I &= \left.\frac{1}{5}\tan^5(\theta)\sec(\theta)\right|_0^{\pi/4} - \frac{1}{5}\int_0^{\pi/4} \tan^5(\theta)\sec(\theta)\tan(\theta)\,\text{d}\theta\\
&= \left.\frac{1}{5}\tan^5(\theta)\sec(\theta)\right|_0^{\pi/4} - \frac{1}{5}\int_0^{\pi/4} \tan^6(\theta)\sec(\theta)\,\text{d}\theta\\
&=  \left.\frac{1}{5}\tan^5(\theta)\sec(\theta)\right|_0^{\pi/4} - \frac{1}{5}I + \frac{1}{5}\int_0^{\pi/4} \tan^4(\theta)\sec(\theta)\,\text{d}\theta\\
&=\frac{1}{5}\sqrt{2} - \frac{1}{5}I + \frac{1}{5}I_2
\end{align}
Now compute $I_2 = \int_0^{\pi/4} \tan^4(\theta)\sec(\theta)\,\text{d}\theta$.
\begin{align}
I_2 &= \int_0^{\pi/4} \tan^4(\theta)\sec(\theta)\,\text{d}\theta \\
&= \int_0^{\pi/4} \left(\sec^4(\theta) - 2\sec^2(\theta)+1\right)\sec(\theta)\,\text{d}\theta\\
&= \int_0^{\pi/4}\sec^5(\theta) \,\text{d}\theta - 2\int_0^{\pi/4}\sec^3(\theta)\,\text{d}\theta + \int_0^{\pi/4}\sec(\theta)\,\text{d}\theta\\
&= \int_0^{\pi/4}\sec^5(\theta)\,\text{d}\theta - \left.\left(\sec(\theta)\tan(\theta) + \ln|\sec(\theta)+\tan(\theta)|\right)\right|_0^{\pi/4} + \left.\ln|\sec(\theta)+\tan(\theta)|\right|_0^{\pi/4}\\
&= \int_0^{\pi/4} \sec^5(\theta)\,\text{d}\theta -\sqrt{2}\\
&= I_3 - \sqrt{2}
\end{align}
Now, compute $I_3 = \int_0^{\pi/4}\sec^5(\theta)\,\text{d}\theta$.

Use integration by parts, with $\text{d}v = \sec^2(\theta)\,\text{d}\theta$, $u = \sec^3(\theta)$ to get:
\begin{align}
I_3 = \int_0^{\pi/4}\sec^5(\theta)\,\text{d}\theta &= \left.\sec^3(\theta)\tan(\theta)\right|_0^{\pi/4} - \int_0^{\pi/4} 3\tan^2(\theta)\sec^3(\theta)\,\text{d}\theta\\
&=2\sqrt{2} - \int_0^{\pi/4} 3(\sec^2(\theta)-1)\sec^3(\theta)\,\text{d}\theta\\
&= 2\sqrt{2}-3I_3 + 3\int_0^{\pi/4}\sec^3(\theta)\,\text{d}\theta\\
&= 2\sqrt{2}-3I_3 + \frac{3}{2}\left(\sqrt{2}+\ln(\sqrt{2}+1)\right)
\end{align}

We conclude that 
$$I_3 = \frac{7}{8}\sqrt{2} + \frac{3}{8}\ln(\sqrt{2}+1)$$

Hence \begin{align}I_2 &= -\sqrt{2}+ I_3 \\
&= -\sqrt{2}+\frac{7}{8}\sqrt{2} + \frac{3}{8}\ln(\sqrt{2}+1)\\
&= -\frac{1}{8}\sqrt{2} + \frac{3}{8}\ln(\sqrt{2}+1)
\end{align}

Concluding, we have 
\begin{align}
\frac{6}{5}I &= \frac{1}{5}\sqrt{2} + \frac{1}{5}I_2\\
&= \frac{1}{5}\sqrt{2}-\frac{1}{40}\sqrt{2} +\frac{3}{40}\ln(\sqrt{2}+1)\\
&= \frac{7}{40}\sqrt{2} + \frac{3}{40}\ln(\sqrt{2}+1)
\end{align}

And hence 
$$I = \frac{7}{48}\sqrt{2} + \frac{1}{16}\ln(\sqrt{2}+1)$$

---

I feel I should emphasize that this is not the easiest way to do this, nor is it even the most straightforward using trig substitution. However, it was what came out when I worked it out the first time from scratch, and sometimes seeing it in such a raw form can be instructive.

(Jack's method is much more elegant, but again, I am posting this to show what sometimes comes of "first attempts" that work out.)

Comment: +1 it is nice to see that sometimes trying a few different methods is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Hint let $t=tan(x)$ so $dt=sec^2(x)dx$ so integral becomes $tan^4(x)sec^3(x)dx$ Now use $tan^2(x)=sec^2(x)-1$ so we get $sec^7(x)-2sec^5(x)+sec^3(x)$ now coorectly use  $\sec^2(x)dx=tan(x),d(sec^{n-2}(x))/dx=(n-2)sec^{n-3}(x)sec(x)tan(x)$